# Typescript double identifier on declaration file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have write a class function that return the instance of myClass if it is not the instance of the class.

```
function myClass(){
    if ( this instanceof myClass )
        return myClass();
}
```

Hence, both new myClass() and myClass() and get the instance of the myClass.

```
myClass(); // return myClass instance
new myClass(); // return myClass instance
```

However, I don't know how to declare the above class in typescript declaration file.

If I write that:

```
class myClass{}
function myClass(): myClass;
```

This will be duplicate identifier error.

Is there any method to fix that? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use different names

```
// Uppercase first letter!
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
}

// lowercase first letter
function getGreeterInstance() {
    return new Greeter("Hello");
}
```

## Explanation

- TypeScript has its conventions, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches if you follow them.
- Use descriptive/self-explanatory names. `myClass` is not clear enough for who reads the code.
- Use different names for you definitions.

## Notes

Make sure to check out TypeScript's documentation on [classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) and [functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).